# Parameter is only sometimes not expanding properly for a condition

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have a template which I've simplified to the following:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: 'releaseChannel'
  type: 'string'
  default: ''
- name: 'createDistribution'
  type: 'boolean'
  default: 'false'

steps:

- task: 'PowerShell@2'
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.createDistribution }}', 'True'))
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    pwsh: true
    script: |
      $releaseChannel = '${{ parameters.releaseChannel }}'
      Write-Host $releaseChannel

- task: 'PowerShell@2'
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.createDistribution }}', 'True'), not('${{ parameters.releaseChannel }}'))
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    pwsh: true
    script: |
      Write-Host 'Success'
```

The issue I'm having is the expansion of the condition for the second step, it's not properly expanding `${{ parameters.releaseChannel }}`, but *is* expanding `${{ parameters.createDistribution }}`:

```
2023-12-07T09:11:59.6112292Z Skipping step due to condition evaluation.
Evaluating: and(succeeded(), eq('True', 'True'), not('$(releaseChannel)'))
Expanded: and(True, eq('True', 'True'), not('$(releaseChannel)'))
Result: False
```

The output of the first step though shows that it does in fact have a value:

```
2023-12-07T09:11:57.9605966Z ##[section]Starting: PowerShell
2023-12-07T09:11:57.9610686Z ==============================================================================
2023-12-07T09:11:57.9610818Z Task         : PowerShell
2023-12-07T09:11:57.9610879Z Description  : Run a PowerShell script on Linux, macOS, or Windows
2023-12-07T09:11:57.9610970Z Version      : 2.231.6
2023-12-07T09:11:57.9611042Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-12-07T09:11:57.9611109Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell
2023-12-07T09:11:57.9611227Z ==============================================================================
2023-12-07T09:11:58.2734104Z Generating script.
2023-12-07T09:11:58.2759813Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2023-12-07T09:11:58.2763785Z [command]/usr/bin/pwsh -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command . '/home/vsts/work/_temp/640b78ec-4ca6-4032-b7d4-aecfb769ce43.ps1'
2023-12-07T09:11:59.5467675Z value
2023-12-07T09:11:59.6097100Z ##[section]Finishing: PowerShell
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I have tested using the template shared by you. `${{ parameters.releaseChannel }}` is expanded correctly.  In the log, I can see `##[debug]Evaluating: and(succeeded(), eq('True', 'True'), not('value'))`.   According to your log, you are using `$(releaseChannel)` instead of `${{ parameters.releaseChannel }}`. Please check whether the condition in your template is correct.

Comment: Thanks @ZiyangLiu-MSFT, perhaps then it's the way I'm calling it from the entry file. My exact test case which failed is here: https://github.com/JonathanLydall/PipelineTesting

Comment: Also, you should see from the example the it should be "value" there, not $(releaseChannel).

Comment: I think I understand the issue, it's that evaluation of the variable occurred upfront before the output variable was set. I have an idea of something I can try, will revert here later today or tomorrow.

Comment: @JonathanL. Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your YAML sample, I can reproduce the same issue.

[image]

The cause of the issue is that the parameter: `releaseChannel` need to accept value at compile. And the variable format:`$(releaseChannel)` will expand the value at runtime.

So the variable value is not able to pass to parameter successfully.

To solve this issue, you can use the format:  `${{variables.releaseChannel}}`

For example:

Azure Pipelines.yml

```
stages:

- stage: 'Stage'
  condition: succeeded()
  variables:
  - name: 'releaseChannel'
    value: 'value'
  jobs:
  - job: 'Job'
    steps:

    - checkout: self
      persistCredentials: 'true'

    - template: 'template.yml'
      parameters:
        createDistribution: true
        releaseChannel: ${{variables.releaseChannel}}
```

Result:

[image]

For more detailed info about variable format, you can refer to this doc: [Runtime expression syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#runtime-expression-syntax)